# Why is this allowed? const nums: number[] = { ...[1, 2, 3] }

Tags: typescript

Just found a critical bug in my typescript codebase due to the fact this was allowed:

```
const nums: number[] = { ...[1, 2, 3] } // should have been [ ...[1,2,3] ]
a.join('-')
// runtime error: a.join is not a function
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgF4YBvGAOmrwEYAaGAJkYGYiBfAKDkoCsQASzAAKAOQBaMQEoYAejkwcKMFEFosMXDhA4kvAcJiCIyELDgwAZiuBrwMLl1CRYGJKky5CJch3mKUACeAA6a2rqUMADiICAAJgCEzuDQMMAe6Nj4RKQU1JQ+-gpmMMFhWjg6OFEAQgCCACKJQA)

Why is an array deconstructed as an object, assignable to array where it can cause an easily preventable runtime exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#34780](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34780).

The type system doesn't have a way to mark `interface` members as "own" or enumerable, so the compiler assumes that all members are copied via the spread operator.   As a heuristic, that's often adequate, but it does the wrong thing for any members set on a prototype, like methods of a class:

```
interface Whoops {
    foo(): void;
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

class Oops implements Whoops {
    foo() { }
    a = 1;
    b = "";
}

const oopsie = (w: Whoops) => ({ ...w });

oopsie(new Oops()).foo(); // no compiler error
// runtime error: oopsie(...).foo is not a function!
```

If you write a `class` declaration directly, the compiler will assume that method declarations are not spreadable:

```
declare class Whoops {
    foo(): void;
    a: number;
    b: string;
}
const oopsie = (w: Whoops) => ({ ...w });
oopsie(new Whoops()).foo(); // compiler time error as expected
// foo does not exist on {a: number; b: string};
```

But unfortunately the [type declarations for `Array<T>` are for an `interface`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1211) and not as a [declared `class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#classes). So when you spread an array into an object the compiler thinks all of the `Array` properties and methods are copied, and therefore that the resulting object conforms to the `Array` interface, and therefore has a `join()` method.  Oopsie.

---

Maaaaybe someone could change the standard libraries so that instead of `interface Array<T>` and `interface ArrayConstructor` and `declare var Array: ArrayConstructor` we just had `declare class Array<T>`, and then `join()` would no longer be seen as spreadable, but I'm not sure.  It seemed to work when I tried it locally on my own system, but I can't easily reproduce this in the Playground or other online IDE, and messing with built-in types like `Array` is not something I'm comfortable doing anyway.

Or maaaaybe the language could be changed so that non-own or non-enumerable properties could be marked on `interface`s, but I wouldn't count on it (see [microsoft/TypeScript#9726](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726))

For now it's a design limitation of TypeScript.  If you feel strongly about this you could go to microsoft/TypeScript#34780 and give it a  and describe how you were bitten by it, but I don't know it'd really do much good.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3jAdJg2gRgDQwBMBAzALowC+AUHOgFYgCWYAFAOQC07AlDAPT8YAJwCuYKEwC2AUxgzhwkMIBc8BszAwmEGGBCwEAM3HBJ4GNWqhIsAEZqwoqXYVYKyFJQFCoATwAHOQUlYXQYAHEQEAATAEJrcGgYYEdnV2F3JFQMbApvQT0QGH8g+UVlcIAhAEEAEQTqMDhZCAC4YDkAdQALaICIJhkcVGoYce0JBSMO7r6QAdGJ5ZgjaNYeNQA3ZhiAbjGV8bg0lwUDo-GHGGhhFgBzC4maZeAAGzgIXQB5Bd1pAJvGSyCS6Xr9XQoQ5HNYgDY5F6XBDIHBPI52bIAIkxaKoVleSVgEKG2VYAHc1OC-nxEAA+GCsNCYdBkqg8XHEmSsMAyVm-AYbHjoWEbPY+GCc1jMoWw7S6fSGVamcxgKw0ZqtdqdGBUgZDQhLCYxGTvODCOSmr46+aLKGXVbrTYwHZMfbQlYnPTpc7u5bXW4PXGI8Y2ZKc0kU60Qmn0xm5Flsjl-Ibc3lRv6C4WOsWFUBSAJMIHCErSYIVYufeQADyCZhkMXdhVlMRAMnlBmrOiJWhQnqcZ2EYv9UDuYHulAO1EoQA)