# Weird non-function property "names" if type argument is an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why are `N` and `NN` below different types?

```
type NonFunctionPropertyNames< T > = {

  [ K in keyof T ]: T[ K ] extends Function ? never : K

}[ keyof T ]; 


//
// This is number | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => number | undefined) | ...
//
type N = NonFunctionPropertyNames< string[] >;

//
// This is number | "length"
//
type NN = {

  [ K in keyof string[] ]: string[][ K ] extends Function ? never : K

}[ keyof string[] ];
```

What looks extremely weird is that, apparently, `N` ends up being a union of property **types** rather than property **names**. E.g., consider the first four members of `N`:

`number | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => number | undefined)`

The first three are the types of the following properties of `string[]`: `length, toString, toLocaleString`. The fourth one is *almost* the type of `pop`, but with `number` instead of `string`. Notice that these properties occur in exactly the same order in `keyof string[]`:

`keyof string[] = ... | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | ...`

So - can anybody explain what exactly is happening here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. (BTW, I use TypeScript 3.9.2.)

Comment: For what it's worth: with the help of the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) I've learned that ```N``` and ```NN``` were the same type up to TS 3.0.1, but they've been different since TS 3.1.6.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741437/why-is-this-allowed-const-nums-number-1-2-3) question of mine may be related. In short, typescript sometime iterates over the prototypes of built ins, and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer: TypeScript 3.1 changed the rules for *homomorphic mapped types* if the type argument is an array. The details are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063); briefly, what's happening in this concrete case is the following:

- When the TS compiler sees that the argument to `NonFunctionPropertyNames` is `string[]`, it does **not** perform the `{ [ K in keyof string[] ] : ... }` iteration.
- Instead, it does the following:

  - Take the type expression after the colon, i.e., `T[ K ] extends Function ? never : K`.
  - Replace `T[ K ]` with `string` and `K` with `number`: the result is `string extends Function ? never: number`.
  - Build an array from the result of this latter type expression: you get `number[]` - this is what the `{ ... }` part of `NonFunctionPropertyNames< string[] >` is resolved to.
- Finally, the `{ ... }` part is indexed with `keyof string[]`, so what you end up with is `number[][ keyof string[] ]`, which is actually the same as `number[][ keyof number[] ]`, i.e., the the union of the **types of all properties** in `number[]`, including both functions and non-functions.

I'm sure that the TypeScript designers had very good reasons for introducing this behavior in 3.1, and the examples given in the description of the [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063) do make a lot of sense. However, I can't help feeling that in this particular case, the interaction of conditional mapped types and array-specific mapping rules leads to a highly non-intuitive result.